# Touchable Elements Translated onto screen do not register touch

Tags: react-native

In my React Native component I have an animation which brings a portion of the component onto screen:

```
<-     screen     -><-hidden->
--------------------++++++++++
|                   |        |
|         <button>  |   XX   |
|                   |        |
|                   |        |
|                   |        |
|                   |        |
--------------------++++++++++
```

When `<button>` is clicked, I have an animation to translate the rest of the component onto the screen. `XX` is a button too, but when that comes into view, it is not clickable. I don't think it's to do with the animation because if I start it at `translateX: -paneWidth`, then it's still not clickable. This is what the screen looks like after transformation:

```
<-hidden-><-     screen     ->
--------------------++++++++++
|                   |        |
|         <button>  |   XX   |
|                   |        |
|                   |        |
|                   |        |
|                   |        |
--------------------++++++++++
```

I found this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28894 but didn't see a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to replace `Switch`, `TouchableOpacity`, etc from "react-native" to "react-native-gesture-handler":

from

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Switch } from "react-native"
```

to

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Switch } from "react-native-gesture-handler"
```

EDIT: This still does not work for TextInputs, from either library.

EDIT2: I made a workaround to make the text inputs work. Not pretty, but it works (kinda)

```
{oneOffInput.current !== undefined && (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      if (oneOffInput.current !== undefined) {
        oneOffInput.current.focus()
      }
    }}
  >
    <TextInput
      value={amountOneOff}
      onChangeText={(v: string) => setAmountOneOff(v)}
      ref={oneOffInput}
    ></TextInput>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```